# Cannot type @£$ symbols in Windows 8.1

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, symbols

I'm having this weird problem with my Windows 8.1 that I'm unable to type-in **`@ £ $`** symbols with my Swedish keyboard.
I know the first probable answer would be to check my keyboard settings and correct it if necessary. However, I have checked/changed that setting 100 times but it didn't help.

To make this issue more interesting, I'm having the exact same settings on my other computer (with Swedish keyboard too) and there I'm able to type-in all those characters.

I'm using *Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 800* (Model 1455). The problem still persists if I plugin some other wired keyboard with Swedish layout.

Is this a known bug in windows? and how to fix this?

For your perusal, I'm attaching the screenshot of my current settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some intensive trouble-shooting (which even took me to perform a fresh install of my windows 8 operating system) I am finally able to resolve this problem.

The problem is actually one of the utility software that comes with my Gigabyte motherboard. Its called **EasyTune** available in **App Center** that controls the overclocking and system performance. Once the program is running or asked to retain its settings after boot, then it disables **@£$** keys system-wide.

[image]

[image]

In my case, I enabled the option **"Retain Smart Fan settings after reboot."** in order to minimize the CPU-fan RPM as I'm using my computer as HTPC and want it to be quite,

Anyhow, disabling the auto-retain options or uninstalling this utility feature is a confirm solution in my case. I hope Gigabyte would release an update which should fix this annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

With a Swedish layout keyboard you will need to install the Swedish language pack. Click `Add Language`, Locate `Swedish (Svenska)`, and click `Move Up`.

After you've done this, go to `Advanced settings` and scroll down to `Switch input methods` and check `Use the desktop language bar when it's available` (Last step not needed, you can also switch between English and Swedish layout with `Alt + Shift`.

The problem is that Swedish keyboards with an English Language installed will not allow you to use `Alt Gr + <number>` and thus make it hard to write special characters.

Comment: Compared to my other computer, I only have English language (with Swedish keyboard) installed and there's nothing i need to switch between input types in order to type those symbols. Another thing is, i'm able to type-in characters like `{ [ ] }` which can only be entered using **Alt Gr** key. The only problem is with these characters `@ £ $`.

Answer (score 0):

Try and install a Danish or German keyboard (you can delete them later) and see if you can produce those characters.

Comment: tried with danish, still no luck